# Windows. Возможно ли забиндить по нажатию клавиши taskkill?

Tags: windows, binding, процесс

Добрый вечер!

Можно ли в ОС Windows задать завершение процесса с определенным названием по нажатию клавиши (сочетания клавиш)? Причем данное действие должно выполняться независимо от того, какое окно активное.

Например: я нахожусь в `Microsoft Office Word`, нажимаю `ctrl+k` - и у меня завершается процесс с названием `notepad.exe`, если он запущен.

Или хотя бы по нажатию клавиш запустить bat-файл?

Comment: Гуглите глобальные хуки.. а вообще, можно поинтересоваться, для чего вам такая странная задача?

Comment: @Mr.Modest мне это нужно для быстрого завершения приложения.

Comment: @Mr.Modest я погуглил глобальные хуки, но как я понял, они мне не позволят обработать нажатие клавиши, когда я нахожусь в другом приложении. Поправьте, если я не так понял.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Нет. [A global hook monitors messages for all threads in the same desktop as the calling thread.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Можно. Даже легко.

Создайте `bat`-файл с нужным вам содержимым и сделайте **ярлык** к нему.

В свойствах ярлыка можно будет назначить горячую клавишу.